# creating a subcounter to a counter I created

Tags: counters

I created a counter, call it `nc`for newcounter:

`\newcounter{nc}`

I want to create a "subcounter", let me call it `snc` for sub new counter, whose behavior mimics the way `subsection` is a "subcounter" to `section`. How do I do this?

If it is not clear what I am asking, here is an example: if the value of `nc` is 4, then I want the value of `snc` to be 4.0, and the next call to `snc` to be 4.1, etc.

This is surely well known but I searched briefly and couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: The term `subcounter` isn't really correct. `section` is the resetting counter of `subsection`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counters that should be reset from other counters are usually defined with `\newcounter{snc}[nc]` where `nc` is the resetting counter.

However, this does not provide the requested format, i.e. `nc.snc`, so `\renewcommand{\thesnc}{\thenc.\arabic{snc}` is needed.

Counters itself can't have a floating point value like `1.1` -- their output is a combination of some counter values which is defined in the relevant `\the...` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{nc}
\newcounter{snc}[nc]

\renewcommand{\thesnc}{\thenc.\arabic{snc}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{nc}{4}

\thenc\ and \thesnc

\stepcounter{snc} 

Now snc has the value \thesnc. 

Let's step nc and look what happens:\stepcounter{nc}

Now snc has the value \thesnc.
\end{document}
```

With the `chngcntr` package this can be simplified a little bit, i.e. for example if `[nc]` has been forgotten in the definition of the `snc` counter, this and the formatting change can be done with the command `\counterwithin{snc}{nc}`. However, `\newcounter{scn}` is still necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newcounter{nc}
\newcounter{snc}

\counterwithin{snc}{nc}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{nc}{4}

\thenc\ and \thesnc

\stepcounter{snc} 

Now snc has the value \thesnc. 

Let's step nc and look what happens:\stepcounter{nc}

Now snc has the value \thesnc.
\end{document}
```

Both styles give following output:

[image]

Comment: what about when using `totcount` packages to get the total of subcounters ? It isn't supported FTM...

Comment: Note: Package `chngcntr` is no longer needed. `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` and the star forms `\counterwithin*` and `\counterwithout*` are provided the by LaTeX kernel from 2018-04-01. See [`ltnews28.pdf`](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews28.pdf).